# what is the sudo -i command

Tags: sudo

What does the sudo -i command do and in which situations would it be used. read it using the man sudo command but i'm looking for a more diluted discription to help me understand better.

Answer (score 11):

sudo lets you run commands in your own user account with root privileges. su lets you switch user so that you're actually logged in as root.

sudo -s runs a shell with root privileges. sudo -i does this as well, but also acquires the root user's environment.

This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bashrc or .login will be read and executed by the shell.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you use `sudo -i` when you know you will be running various commands that need root access and don't want to run each of them with `sudo`. To illustrate:

```
$ whoami
terdon
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for terdon: 
# whoami
root
```

So, after running `sudo -i` all subsequent commands you run will be run as though you had run them with `sudo`. You are now logged in as `root` and no longer need `sudo` to gain privileges.